# More efficient way to query for column permutations in SQLite

Tags: python, performance, sqlite, query-optimization, permutation

For dummy's sake, let's say that I have a database with columns `text`, `ind` and `sentid`. You can think of it as a database with one row per word, with a word's text, its position in the sentence, and the ID of the sentence.

To query for specific occurrences of `n` words, I join the table with itself `n` times. That table does not have a unique column except for the default `rowid`. I oftentimes want to query these columns in such a way that the integers in the `n` `ind` columns are sequential without any integer between them. Sometimes the order matters, sometimes the order does not. At the same time, each of the `n` columns also needs to fulfil some requirement, e.g. `n0.text = 'a' AND n1.text = 'b' AND n2.text = 'c'`. Put differently, in every sentence (unique `sentid`), find all occurrences of `a b c` either ordered or in any order (but sequential).

I have solved the ordered case quite easily. For three columns with names ind0, ind1, ind2 you could simply have a query like the following and scale it accordingly as `n` columns grows.

```sql
WHERE ind1 = ind0 + 1 AND ind2 = ind1 + 1
```

Perhaps there is a better way (do tell me if that is so) but I have found that this works reliably well in terms of performance (query speed).

The tougher nut to crack is those cases where the integers also have to be sequential but where the order does not matter (e.g., `7 9 8`, `3 1 2`, `11 10 9`). My current approach is "brute forcing" by simply generating all possible permutations of orders (e.g., `(ind1 = ind0 + 1 AND ind2 = ind1 + 1) OR (ind0 = ind1 + 1 AND ind2 = ind0 + 1) OR ...`)). But as `n` grows, this becomes a huge list of possibilities and my query speed seems to be really hurting on this. For example, for `n=6` (the max requirement) this will generate 720 potential orders separate with OR. Such an approach, that works, is given as a minimal but documented example below for you to try out.

I am looking for a more generic, SQL-y solution that hopefully positively impacts performance when querying for sequential (but not necessarily ordered) columns.

Fiddle with data and current implementation [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=d10ebe4d6fe984eae3c78103cbd9856c), reproducible Python code below.

Note that it *is* possible to get multiple results per sentid, but only if at least one of the word indices differs in the three matched words. E.g. permutations *of the results themselves* are not needed. E.g., 1-2-0 and 3-2-1 can both be valid results for one sentid, but both 1-2-0 and 2-1-0 can't.

```py
import sqlite3
from itertools import permutations
from pathlib import Path
from random import shuffle


def generate_all_possible_sequences(n: int) -> str:
    """Given an integer, generates all possible permutations of the 'n' given indices with respect to
    order in SQLite. What this means is that it will generate all possible permutations, e.g., for '3':
    0, 1, 2; 0, 2, 1; 1, 0, 2; 1, 2, 0 etc. and then build corresponding SQLite requirements, e.g.,
    0, 1, 2: ind1 = ind0 + 1 AND ind2 = ind1 + 1
    0, 2, 1: ind2 = ind0 + 1 AND ind1 = ind2 + 1
    ...

    and all these possibilities are then concatenated with OR to allow every possibility:
    ((ind1 = ind0 + 1 AND ind2 = ind1 + 1) OR (ind2 = ind0 + 1 AND ind1 = ind2 + 1) OR ...)
    """
    idxs = list(range(n))

    order_perms = []
    for perm in permutations(idxs):
        this_perm_orders = []
        for i in range(1, len(perm)):
            this_perm_orders.append(f"w{perm[i]}.ind = w{perm[i-1]}.ind + 1")
        order_perms.append(f"({' AND '.join(this_perm_orders)})")

    return f"({' OR '.join(order_perms)})"


def main():
    pdb = Path("temp.db")

    if pdb.exists():
        pdb.unlink()

    conn = sqlite3.connect(str(pdb))
    db_cur = conn.cursor()
    # Create a table of words, where each word has its text, its position in the sentence, and the ID of its sentence
    db_cur.execute("CREATE TABLE tbl(text TEXT, ind INTEGER, sentid INTEGER)")

    # Create dummy data
    vals = []
    for sent_id in range(20):
        shuffled = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "c"]
        shuffle(shuffled)
        for word_id, word in enumerate(shuffled):
            vals.append((word, word_id, sent_id))

    # Wrap the values in single quotes for SQLite
    vals = [(f"'{v}'" for v in val) for val in vals]
    # Convert values into INSERT commands
    cmds = [f"INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ({','.join(val)})" for val in vals]
    # Build DB
    db_cur.executescript(f"BEGIN TRANSACTION;{';'.join(cmds)};COMMIT;")

    print(f"BEGIN TRANSACTION;{';'.join(cmds)};COMMIT;\n")

    # Query DB for sequential occurences in ind0, ind1, and ind2: the order does not matter
    # but they have to be sequential
    query = f"""SELECT w0.ind, w1.ind, w2.ind, w0.sentid
FROM tbl AS w0
JOIN tbl AS w1 USING (sentid)
JOIN tbl AS w2 USING (sentid)
WHERE w0.text = 'a'
    AND w1.text = 'b'
    AND w2.text = 'c'
    AND {generate_all_possible_sequences(3)}"""

    print(query)
    print()

    print("a_idx\tb_idx\tc_idx\tsentid")
    for res in db_cur.execute(query).fetchall():
        print("\t".join(map(str, res)))

    db_cur.close()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    pdb.unlink()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider a different design where instead of a row with n columns there is a table with n rows (for each of your current rows) containing only a key column and an integer.

Comment: @forpas Unfortunately that is not possible because the `n` columns are a result of `n` joins.

Comment: If this is not a table then is there any unique column?

Comment: Except for `rowid`, the original table (before JOINing) does not have a unique column, no.

Comment: If the data that you have is the result of joins maybe the filtering can be done better in the initial query. Post that code and sample data better in a fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39

Comment: @forpas Please see my edit (at the bottom). Does that give a better idea of my use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the easiest way to implement this is to use the following condition:

```sql
AND MAX(w0.ind, w1.ind, w2.ind) - MIN(w0.ind, w1.ind, w2.ind) = 2
```

where 2 = the number of words that we are looking for -1. That being said, it is hard to say much about the performance since "no, indexes can't be used in expressions like MAX(...) - MIN(...) where functions are used." as [@forpas mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73261093/more-efficient-way-to-query-for-column-permutations-in-sqlite/73267310?noredirect=1#comment129404681_73267310).

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that uses mostly the `rowid`s to create all the possible permutations:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT t0.rowid rowid0, t1.rowid rowid1, t2.rowid rowid2
  FROM tbl AS t0
  JOIN tbl AS t1 ON t1.sentid = t0.sentid AND t1.ind = t0.ind + 1
  JOIN tbl AS t2 ON t2.sentid = t1.sentid AND t2.ind = t1.ind + 1
)
SELECT t0.ind ind0, t1.ind ind1, t2.ind ind2 
FROM cte c
JOIN tbl t0 ON t0.rowid IN (c.rowid0, c.rowid1, c.rowid2)
JOIN tbl t1 ON t1.rowid IN (c.rowid0, c.rowid1, c.rowid2) AND t1.rowid <> t0.rowid
JOIN tbl t2 ON t2.rowid IN (c.rowid0, c.rowid1, c.rowid2) AND t2.rowid NOT IN (t0.rowid, t1.rowid)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=e91a022d71cdd77b33f085a0e49605cb).

The query plan (in the above demo) shows that SQLite uses covering indexes and the `rowid`s to perform the joins.
I don't know how this would scale for more columns as this requirement is a performance killer by design because of the multiple joins and the number of rows that must be retuned for each tuple of *n* columns that satisfy the conditions (=*n!*).

Comment: This looks promising. I will test some things out and get back to you. For cases where there are other restrictions, e.g. t0.text = 'x' AND t1.text = 'y', should the WHERE clause go in the first `cte` table or after the final joins? (ps: what does cte stand for?) Thanks!

Comment: @BramVanroy the CTE returns ordered results and the main query shuffles them and creates all the permutations. If you want to set the conditions in the ordered results then place them inside the CTE.

Comment: Oh gosh, I made a mistake in my edit, which by my fault has lead you to suggest a solution that does not work for my case. The problem is that in fact the order of the elements does not matter in the database, but the found representation should only be presented once. So if a given sentid has "0 2 1", it should only return that "0 2 1" and not "0 1 2" by reordering the elements. It's hard to explain what I mean but I hope that you understand. So per sentence, the same 3 elements should only be returned once (in their database order - be that 0 1 2 or 2 1 0, as long as its sequential.

Comment: I'm sure that this must be frustrating for you. I will updated the edit now. I will also add a bounty to the question as soon as I can to remotivate you to reconsider the edits, and I +1'd your current answer for your trouble.

Comment: @BramVanroy the way that the dataset is produced in your code by the 3 joins returns all possible permutations, so I don't understand how a given sentid has "0 2 1" but not "0 1 2". Unless you do some kind of filtering. I suggest that you use this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39 to post sample data (just like the demo in my answer) and the query that creates your initial filtered dataset so I can test my query.

Comment: I hope that this example helps: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=d10ebe4d6fe984eae3c78103cbd9856c. It might help to think of it in terms of that example, where you are looking for an occurrence of "a b c" in a given sentid, but where the order of those does not matter (as long as they are sequential). So every joined table basically has a requirement attached to it (each one's `text` has to be a distinct letter in this example).

Comment: Will have to do more testing, but I think this may work as an extra condition (because `ind` is unique within every `sentid`): `AND MAX(w0.ind, w1.ind, w2.ind) - MIN(w0.ind, w1.ind, w2.ind) = 2`, where 2 = the number of words that we are looking for `-1`.

Comment: @BramVanroy I have asked you in a comment under your question if there is any unique column in the table and you answered no. Also I don't see in the table's definition, neither in your Python code nor in the demo link, any unique constraint or unique index for the combination of ind and sentid, something like: `CREATE TABLE tbl(text TEXT, ind INTEGER, sentid INTEGER, UNIQUE(ind, sentid))`. If there is such a constraint then you got your solution.

Comment: And there is no unique column in the _whole table_ indeed... but within every group of sentid the ind column has unique values. So if you query for `sentid=1`, then all the `ind` values that you get *for that specific `sentid`* will be uniqe. But in the whole table, no columns have only unique values.

Comment: @BramVanroy no unique column, but a unique combination of 2 columns and this must be defined in the table's definition with the keyword UNIQUE to avoid erratic rows. In any case `MAX(...) - MIN(...) = n-1` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not know a lot about SQL to realise that this was what you meant. If you add the max/min to your answer I'll accept it. I fear that this won't make use of indexing (as the sentid is used as an index), so maybe this won't be as fast as I had hoped. But hopefully an improvement to my earlier attempt.

Comment: @BramVanroy no, indexes can't be used in expressions like `MAX(...) - MIN(...)` where functions are used. As for the answer, since you proposed it, you can post the code as an answer and accept it.